# ufw rules for Selenium grid

Tags: networking, server, firewall, ufw

I use Selenium grid docker container on my server which could be accessed from the web by http://IP_address:4444.
Please help me to figure out how can I filter or disable this connection by adding some rules to ufw?
I've tried something like this:

```
sudo ufw deny http/tcp
sudo ufw deny out http/tcp
sudo ufw deny 4444
sudo ufw deny out 4444
```

Unfortunately none of these is working.

Answer (score 0):

Your docker container might be bypassing the ufw rules, for that you can go to or create `/etc/docker/daemon.json` then add `{ "iptables": false }` then reload then reload docker `sudo systemctl reload docker`

If that still dont work you can try to be sure that ufw is enabled `sudo ufw enable` then allow incomings connexion from your local network like this `sudo ufw allow 192.168.1.0/24` ( replace 192.168.1.0 by your local network address if it is different ) then block all all incoming connection to port 4444 like this `sudo ufw deny in 4444`

Now if you do `sudo ufw status` you should see something like

> Status: active
>
> To                         Action      From
> --                         ------      ---- 4444                       DENY IN     Anywhere Anywhere                   ALLOW IN
> 192.168.1.0/24

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
"sudo ufw deny in 4444" has no effect at all. I still can access my server from anywhere by port 4444. I have no idea what is going on)

Comment: you can try sudo ufw reset then sudo ufw deny proto tcp from any to any port 4444 and if that does not work what does sudo ufw status give you ?

Comment: I have tried these commands and I get this

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
4444/tcp                   DENY        Anywhere                  
4444/tcp (v6)              DENY        Anywhere (v6) 

But I can still view the web interface on port 4444.
Seems ufw doesn't work.

Comment: are you sure your selenium is using the 4444 port Selenium Grid may use other ports for distributed testing ? another possibilities is that your Docker container is bypassing the ufw rules, for that you can go to or create /etc/docker/daemon.json {
  "iptables": false
} then reload

Comment: Yep, thanks. I guess the docker indeed can avoid ufw rules. The port is 4444 definitely.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Everything works fine. After creating  /etc/docker/daemon.json { "iptables": false } I managed to adjust ufw properly. I hope disabling iptables for docker would not affect system security?

Comment: with ufw enabled and since you only allow from your local network 192.168.1.0/24 you should be okay, I have updated my question, don't forget to validate it if it fit your demand

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as simple as it can be.

Docker uses iptables and automatically updates its rules according to your docker compose or docker run parameters.

If you expose a port through Docker, this port gets exposed no matter what rules your firewall has configured.

But you can give instructions to docker engine to expose ports internally:

docker run:

> ```
> -p 127.0.0.1:27017:27017
> ```

docker compose:

> ```
> ports:
>   - "127.0.0.1:4444:4444"
> ```

Rest of ufw rules will work properly until they are not overrided by Docker.